# jQuery .getJSON() does not show data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm getting this output:

```
0 [object Object] 
1 [object Object] 
2 [object Object] 
3 [object Object]
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON(url, {
    sessionId: "1"
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Successfully got the messages! ");

    $target.empty();

    var messages = [];

    $.each(data,function(k,v) {

        console.log(k + " " + v);

    });


    $target.append(data);
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Could not reload messages!");
});
```

The response:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2014-02-19",
    "user_viewer": null,
    "message": "Hey mate, can you do 20:00?",
    "user_op": "john",
    "time": "18:21:00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2014-02-20",
    "user_viewer": null,
    "message": "@simon, you can borrow one from the desk, it's 1 pound.",
    "user_op": "roger",
    "time": "00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the question? This is the correct behavior.

Comment: need to print out keys and values

Comment: You are getting the exact output that you should be getting.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$.getJSON(url, {
    sessionId: "1"
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Successfully got the messages! ");

    $target.empty();

    var messages = [];

    $.each(data,function(k,v) {
        console.log(k + " " + JSON.stringify(v));
    });


    $target.append(data);
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Could not reload messages!");
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit more what the problem is and how `JSON.stringify` solves it?

Comment: v is now returning this: {"date":"2014-02-19","user_viewer":null,"message":"Hey mate, can you do 20:00?","user_op":"john","time":"18:21:00"}. However, when i try to read it using var item = JSON.stringify(v); console.log(item.message); it does not work. any idea why?

Comment: @chuckfinley `JSON.stringify(v)` will return you the string representation of the object. You cannot access the key `message` of a string.

Comment: Yes. Use `var item = v;`. `JSON.stringify` returns the strigified version, so it is a string.

Comment: @MinkoGechev so this doesn't help me. How do i access the elements?

Comment: Use `var item = v; console.log(item.message);`. This way you access the elements. `JSON.stringify` helps only to print them in a useful form.